# Java function that should return a 9 char random string

Tags: java, string, random

The function is really simple i just can't figure out what's wrong.

```
 private String genRandKey() {
    rnd.setSeed(datetime.getTime());
    String keyset = "abcdefghijklmABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!\"Ł$%^&*()_+-=[]{}:@~;'#<>?|\\,./";
    String key = new String();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        key.concat(String.valueOf(keyset.charAt(rnd.nextInt(keyset.length() - 1))));

    }
    return key;
}
```

It just ends up returning an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A faster and simple way is to use a StringBuilder (used for building strings)

```
StringBuilder key = new StringBuilder(9);
while(key.length() < 9)
    key.append(keyset.charAt(rnd.nextInt(keyset.length() - 1)));
return key.toString();
```

Comment: the only problem with this is that it is a server application and i want it to be as fast as possible and using objects in some cases just slows down the program, but i agree this is the right answer.

Comment: The code above uses far less objects than in your example.  You can recycle the StringBuilder and return it instead of a String copy.  This would mean no objects are created each time.

Answer (score 3):

`concat` returns a new string, it can't modify the original string, they are immutable, i suggest using a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28char%29)

Answer (score 2):

String is immutable object so you need to do

```
key = key.concat(String.valueOf(keyset.charAt(rnd.nextInt(keyset.length() - 1))));
```